# Using Session value in Config File : CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I wish to use username [a session variable] in one of my config file, which is located in `/config` folder of my CI setup.

something like this,

`$config['user_path'] = "./src/img/".$this->session->userdata("username");`

but I get error that session is undefined. I have already auto-loaded `session` in `/config/autoload.php`. Could anyone please tell how to load session library in config file. I have work around but I wanted to know if its possible to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: i think config doesn't have autoload files you can try to print your session in config

Comment: Not able to access session in config file, getting error `Undefined property: CI_Config::$session` Also $_SESSION['username'] is not available. Guess CI session and php $_SESSION are different.

Comment: you can overwrite config values from controller via $this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');

Comment: yes! that is the workaround. But isn't there anyway using session in config file?

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter doesn't use $_SESSION global variable. It uses it's own sessions...

> The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates
>   its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers. 
>   See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

There is a way - Rakesh Sharma wrote about it...

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', $this->session->userdata('youritem'));
```

You can use it in constructor for example.

I don't know any other way how to do it. `$CI =& get_instance();` seems to not work in config files...